# I'm trying to take out seconds in a value that shows HH:MM:SS

Tags: r

Using r in RStudio.

I have data that looks like this:
00:00:00 - 00:59:59 
01:00:00 - 01:59:59
etc.

I want to transform the whole column of data to just show as:
0:00 - 0:59
01:00 - 1:59
etc.

I feel like the solutions is using str_replace somehow, but the regular expression stuff I've looked up doesn't seem to help with this particular solution. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `gsub(":\\d+(?= |$)|^\\d|(?<= )\\d","",your_data,perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with str_sub from the `stringr` package, like this

```
c <- tibble(v1 = c('00:00:00 - 00:59:59','01:00:00 - 01:59:59'))  %>%
#split your column into two separate columns
  separate(v1,into = c('v2','v3'),sep =' - ',remove = FALSE) %>%
#remove the seconds
  mutate_at(2:3, ~ str_sub(.,end=-4)) %>%
#paste it back together
  mutate(v4 = paste(v2,v3,sep=' - ')) %>%
#have a look at the original and fixed columns
  select(v1,v4)
```

Comment: Thank you, that part worked, the issue is the entire value is "00:00:00 - 00:59:59", so running that only got me to "00:00:00 - 00:59" as the value. Do you know how I can take out the seconds in the 00:00:00 as well?

Comment: my apologies, I didn't read your initial post carefully enough. this is a working solution now